# webserver in vertx not working

Tags: ruby, vert.x

The above problem is resolved. But got a new one. The webserver is not starting.
I have put the below code in server.rb file

```
# require "vertx"
# web_server_conf = {
#   'port' => 8080,
#   'host' => 'localhost'
# }
# # Start the web server, with the config we defined above
# Vertx.deploy_verticle('mod-web-server', web_server_conf)
require "vertx"
include Vertx
@server = NetServer.new.connect_handler { |socket|
Pump.new(socket, socket).start
}.listen(8080, 'localhost')
```

When i use `vertx run server.rb` the cursor goes in the next line and then nothing happens. Even localhost:8080 doesn't work. Tried both, commented and uncommented code.
Can some body help me please!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just running the [example webserver](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/blob/master/src/raw/ruby/http/http_server.rb) from the [Ruby examples](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/tree/master/src/raw/ruby) using the [specified command line](https://github.com/vert-x/vertx-examples/tree/master/src/raw/ruby#http) call?

Comment: So now, there seems to be a tcp problem as the webserver is starting but no response from localhost.  Any help!!!

Comment: If the examples aren't working, I'm not sure what you have got set up wrong :-/

Comment: The problem is only with connecting to localhost. I mean, the server is starting. Only telnet is not giving response and localhost not connecting. What can be the problem?

Comment: That's an http server...  Have you tried a browser?  For telnetting, try the `echo` example, I just ran it with `vertx run echo/echo_server.rb` then I could run `telnet localhost 1234` and anything I typed was echoed

Comment: I don't know what to suggest...  Try reinstalling vertx?  Maybe try with [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/) if you're not on Windows?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Found the problem. Had to source the bashrc file